# java regex match 0-9 and some special characters

Tags: java, regex

I'm having some trouble writing a regex for a telephone numbers. (not too great at them yet)
The number may only contain: `0-9,+,/,.,-, ,(,)`
I was thinking:

```
@Pattern(regexp = "(0-9+/\\.\\- \\(\\))?")
```

But that already complains when I just enter 100.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this regex `[0-9\.\-\s+\/()]+`

But according to your explanation and thus my regex it would also allow `+++` or a single space or anything like that, is that what you want?

EDIT: so it might be better to use the following: `([\.\-\s+\/()]*[0-9][\.\-\s+\/()]*){8,15}`

Which requires at least 8-15 numbers and allows the other characters to appear between them.

Comment: Well, not what I want but it is what I need. Our web designer is a tad too fond of allowing our users a lot of freedom and trusting their good will to enter accurate data.

Answer (score 1):

The correct pattern: `^[\d\/\(\)\- \.]+$`

By splitting the regex you can see:

```
^    #Won't match if it doesn't start at the beginning
[    #The character can contain...
\d   #digits
\/   #slash
\(   #brackets (open)
\)   #brackets (close)
\-   #hyphen
     #space (\s is also possible but can be tab too)
\.   #or a dot
]
+   #The character can be repeated
$   #Won't match if it doesn't reach the end
```

Comment: I think you don't need to escape neither backslash nor brackets within character class

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a character class by using square brackets around.

```
[0-9+/. ()-]+
```

See [this expression on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vmhl)

That means match any of the characters from inside the class one or more times (because of the quantifier `+` at the end)

But this will match those characters in **any** order, e.g. "....." would match.

Your regex `(0-9+/\\.\\- \\(\\))?` behaves this way:

Match "0-" then a sequence of nines followed by "/.- ()". Because of the `?` after the surrounding brackets the whole pattern is optional, i.e. it would match the empty string also.

See [your expression on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vmhc)

Comment: @SureshSankar this will match any string that consist only of the characters "0-9+/.\\- ()". so this will allow a lot of freedom, and e.g. "++++((((" would match.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `"[-0-9+/. ()]+"` - special characters are handled differently inside `[]`, and the best way to deal with the `-` is to put it first.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Pattern(regexp = "^[0-9+/. ()-]+$")
```